# Importing existing aws AppSync pipeline resolver into aws CDK

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-cdk, aws-appsync, aws-cdk-typescript

I have an AppSync api created with AWS Amplify. The api has a mutation named `createSpeaker` which is connected to a pipeline resolver. Amplify have created 4 AppSync functions that is triggered by the resolver.

I want to modify this resolver to add an extra appSync function that is triggered when a user calls the `createSpeaker` mutation. This new function is supposed to handle logic that automatically creates logs in a sepparate db.

I am stuck on the step where I am trying to add the new AppSync function to the resolver pipeline, because I can't figure out how to import the existing pipeline resolver into CDK.

Do anyone know how to do this?

In a new CDK app I am importing the API

```js
/** importing the existing api */
const api = appsync.GraphqlApi.fromGraphqlApiAttributes(this, 'api', {
  graphqlApiId: props.appSyncId,
});

/** adding a lambda fn created earlier in this code as data source */
const lambdaDataSource = api.addLambdaDataSource(props.appName + ' - ' + props.appEnv + '-lambdaLoggerDataSource', props.createLoggLambdaFn);

/** 
 * creating a new Appsync fn with js as runtime, that will invoke the lambda function (which is supposed to handle the logic)
 * I want to connect this appSync fn to other resolvers, so that I can log data to DynamoDB
 */
const appSyncFunction = new appsync.AppsyncFunction(this, props.appName + ' - ' + props.appEnv + '-CreateLoggResolverFn', {
  api: api,
  runtime: appsync.FunctionRuntime.JS_1_0_0,
  dataSource: lambdaDataSource,
  name: props.appName + ' - ' + props.appEnv + '-CreateLoggResolverFn',
  code: appsync.Code.fromAsset('lib/appsync/resolver'),
  description: 'This function should be part of other resolvers to logg data to dynamoDB',
});

/** Next step, where I am stuck, is how to import the resolver from the api and add appSyncFunction to it */
```

I have already successfully created this logic through clicking in the console, but I want to automate this when creating new enviroment.

In the end I want to connect all the mutations in the app to create this logs. The logs are ment as both a security feature and a practical feature (readable queryable logs). For now this is a separate CDK app, but I will also add this as part of the Amplify add custom feature.